# Ruby FileUtils.mv invalid multibyte character

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I'm use FileUtils.mv to move folder like this:

```
FileUtils.mv("/home/sean/_site/", "/home/sean/projects/_site/")
```

its returns  `invalid multibyte character` error, the reason is the `_site` folder contains the following files:

```
?????ʼ???????????????
????fedora????ʱ??ʾcannot-open-font-file-true?İ취
?˿?????firefox????????
?ȸ?gaeӦ???̵?
??ǧ??ǧѰ???ⲿ??Ʒ???ɹ??ĵط?
```

but I don't know how to solve it, and when I use system command everything is ok, like this:

```
mv /home/sean/_site /home/sean/projects/_site
```

My system is ubuntu 12.04 LTS server, ruby is 2.0.0p195.

PS: On Debian system the `FileUtils.mv` command its ok.

Answer (score 1):

Just like in bash, don't append a slash if you want to move the folder (and not its content):

```
FileUtils.mv("/home/sean/_site", "/home/sean/projects/_site")
```